# DataFormatString in CodeBehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to fix the way in which dates shows in my Gridview,
I have tried this:

```
private void Temp_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)     
{
        if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[6].Attributes.Add("DataFormatString", "{0:d}");
        }
}
```

Since the gridvirws are generating while runnig, I can't do it as i would normally do:

```
<asp:BoundField DataFormatString="{0:d}" DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Date" />
```

so I can I I do it? 
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean the GridViews are generated while running?

Comment: @mason I mean that  I did this: GridView Grid = new gridview(); in `CodeBehind`, So in my web form, this grid doesn't exist until its creation in the `CodeBehind`

Comment: That's usually a bad idea, because it's doubtful that you're creating this at the right stage in the code behind. But anyways, there's no need to wait until it's data bound to apply formatting. Just modify the column definitions within it programatically when you create it.

Comment: @mason I don't have a lot of choices since the amount of grids that I need is variable. Can you please show me the code?

Comment: Perhaps databind time is too late, by then the data will have already been formatted for display. Is there an event for row created? I.e. set the format before the databind.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how many grids your page will have, it might be a good idea to use a `Repeater`. If you do so, you will be able to use the `DataFormatString` property of the `BoundField` like you said.